# I am using date picker in my flutter app, but when I import it I get several errors

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRangePicker;

and I get the above errors:

1)Error: The getter 'display1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

2)Error: The getter 'subhead' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

3)Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

4)Error: The getter 'body2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

5)Error: The getter 'headline' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

Any help? The datepicker was working great on my app until some months ago. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your flutter version? The names of the texthemes have changed. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60864190/6704033

Comment: My flutter version is 2.5.1. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the commenter said, you were using the older version of the `TextTheme` class. Each of the styles you listed have changed names. Read the link provided by the commenter above.